# Pydantic how to get relationship value

Tags: sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic

I need to get one value from relationship Many-to-one model in `pydantic` `BaseModel`.
How can I do this?

**My children class**

```py
class Picnic(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'picnic'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    city_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('city.id'), nullable=False)

    city = relationship('City', backref='picnics')


class City(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'city'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(String, unique=True, nullable=False, index=True)
```

I need to get city name value :

```py
class Picnics(BaseModel):
    id: int
    # city: str[CityBaseInDB.name] not working
    # city: str = Field(source='city.name') not working 
    # city_name: str not working


    class Config:
        orm_mode: bool = True
```

Comment: A validator can change the value being returned from the value being set; have you looked at using them? https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/

Comment: Thanks for suggest, it really works, but in swagger scheme also displated city object : 'city': {'name': 'string'}

Comment: What is your definition for the field? It would have to be a `str` field, and then use the validator to convert a `City` object.

Comment: @MatsLindh could you provide an example of using the validator to convert a `City` object on `Schema`?

Comment: @wiltonsr Ask a new question if you have a specific question so you can provide proper details; if you're using it for a schema in FastAPI it'll be done automagic for you when you create a pydantic model with the expected fields; how this schema would look depends on how you want to process it further in your request. If you just want to do it separately in Pydantic it also depends on what kind of input you have and want to get out on the other side.

Comment: @MatsLindh I posted another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72702693/how-to-get-separately-column-from-sqlalchemy-relationship-using-pydantic-schema).

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a pydantic model for your parent model too and put it as the type in the relationship field.

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class City(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name: str

    class Config:
        orm_mode: bool = True


class Picnics(BaseModel):
    id: int
    city: City

    class Config:
        orm_mode: bool = True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session, relationship, sessionmaker, Query
from pydantic import BaseModel

Base = declarative_base()
engine = create_engine("sqlite://", echo=True)


class Picnic(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'picnic'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    city_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('city.id'), nullable=False)

    city = relationship('City', backref='picnics')


class City(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'city'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(String, unique=True, nullable=False, index=True)


class PicnicModel(BaseModel):
    id: int
    # city: str[CityBaseInDB.name] not working
    # city: str = Field(source='city.name') not working
    city_name: str

    class Config:
        orm_mode: bool = True


picnic = Picnic(city=City(name='Shenzhen'))
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
LocalSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
db: Session = LocalSession()
db.add(picnic)
db.commit()

q: Query = db.query(Picnic.id, City.name.label('city_name'))
q = q.select_from(Picnic).join(City)
row = q.one_or_none()
model = PicnicModel.from_orm(row)
print(model)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).