# How to get separately column from sqlalchemy relationship using pydantic schema

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic

I have 4 tables: `Hardware`, `SoftwareName`, `SoftwareVersion`, and `Software`.

The `Software` table has an `one-to-many` relationship with `SoftwareName` table and `SoftwareVersion` table. Finally, the `Hardware` model has an `one-to-many` relationship with `Software` table.

I'm trying to get just a specific column from a model relationship using `Pydantic Schema`.

Now I'm getting this output:

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "hostname": "hostname2",
    "softwares": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "software_name": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "nginx"
        },
        "software_version": {
          "id": 1,
          "version": "2.9"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "software_name": {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "vim"
        },
        "software_version": {
          "id": 2,
          "version": "0.3"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "software_name": {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "apache"
        },
        "software_version": {
          "id": 3,
          "version": "1.0"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

But what I expect is this output:

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "hostname": "hostname2",
    "softwares": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "nginx",
        "version": "2.9"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "vim",
        "version": "0.3"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "apache",
        "version": "1.0"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I have the file `main.py`:

```python
   
import uvicorn
from typing import Any, Iterator, List, Optional
from faker import Faker
from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session, sessionmaker, relationship
from faker.providers import DynamicProvider

software_name = DynamicProvider(
     provider_name="software_name",
     elements=["bash", "vim", "vscode", "nginx", "apache"],
)


software_version = DynamicProvider(
     provider_name="software_version",
     elements=["1.0", "2.9", "1.1", "0.3", "2.0"],
)


hardware = DynamicProvider(
     provider_name="hardware",
     elements=["hostname1", "hostname2", "hostname3", "hostname4", "hostname5"],
)

fake = Faker()

# then add new provider to faker instance
fake.add_provider(software_name)
fake.add_provider(software_version)
fake.add_provider(hardware)


engine = create_engine("sqlite:///.db", connect_args={"check_same_thread": False})
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=True, autoflush=True, bind=engine)

Base = declarative_base(bind=engine)


class Software(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'software'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    hardware_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('hardware.id'))
    name_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('software_name.id'))
    version_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('software_version.id'))

    software_name = relationship('SoftwareName', backref='software_name')
    software_version = relationship('SoftwareVersion',
                                    backref='software_version')


class SoftwareName(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'software_name'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)


class SoftwareVersion(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'software_version'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    version = Column(String)


class Hardware(Base):
    __tablename__ = "hardware"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    hostname = Column(String, nullable=False)

    softwares = relationship(Software)


Base.metadata.drop_all()
Base.metadata.create_all()

class BaseSchema(BaseModel):
    id: int

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True


class SoftwareNameSchema(BaseSchema):
    name: str


class SoftwareVersionSchema(BaseSchema):
    version: str


class SoftwareSchema(BaseSchema):
    software_name: SoftwareNameSchema
    software_version:  SoftwareVersionSchema


class HardwareOut(BaseSchema):
    hostname: str
    softwares: List[SoftwareSchema]


app = FastAPI()


@app.on_event("startup")
def on_startup() -> None:
    session = SessionLocal()

    for _ in range(10):
        software_list = []
        for _ in range(3):
            sn = SoftwareName(name=fake.software_name())
            sv = SoftwareVersion(version=fake.software_version())
            s = Software(software_name=sn, software_version=sv)
            software_list.append(s)

        h = Hardware(hostname=fake.hardware(), softwares=software_list)
        session.add(h)
        session.flush()

    session.close()


def get_db() -> Iterator[Session]:
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()


@app.get("/hardwares", response_model=List[HardwareOut])
def get_hardwares(db: Session = Depends(get_db)) -> Any:
    return [HardwareOut.from_orm(hardware) for hardware in db.query(Hardware).all()]
```

How can I change the `HardwareOut` Schema to return what I expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got the answer I wanted.

I added 2 changes to get it:

1. Use the `Union` type from `typing` lib for the attributes `software_name` e `software_version` like that:
2. Add a Pydantic `validator` for each field to change the returned value, like that:

```python
from typing import Union
from pydantic import validator

...

class SoftwareSchema(BaseSchema):
    software_name: Union[str, SoftwareNameSchema]
    software_version:  Union[str, SoftwareVersionSchema]

    @validator('software_name')
    def name_to_str(cls, v, values, **kwargs):
        return v.name if not isinstance(v, str) else v

    @validator('software_version')
    def version_to_str(cls, v, values, **kwargs):
        return v.version if not isinstance(v, str) else v

...
```

And the answer was this:

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "hostname": "hostname2",
    "softwares": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "software_name": "nginx",
        "software_version": "2.9"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "software_name": "vim",
        "software_version": "0.3"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "software_name": "apache",
        "software_version": "1.0"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

update:

As an improvement, I add an alias for each attribute for a better semantic response. So, I change `software_name` to `name` and `software_version` to `version`. Like this:

```python
from typing import Union
from pydantic import validator

...

class SoftwareSchema(BaseSchema):
    software_name: Union[str, SoftwareNameSchema] = Field(None, alias="name")
    software_version:  Union[str, SoftwareVersionSchema] = Field(None, alias="version")

    @validator('software_name')
    def name_to_str(cls, v, values, **kwargs):
        return v.name if not isinstance(v, str) else v

    @validator('software_version')
    def version_to_str(cls, v, values, **kwargs):
        return v.version if not isinstance(v, str) else v

...
```